# CSS a:link,a:active,a:visited dont apply on my tags

Tags: css, css-selectors, anchor

I got the following CSS rule in my page:

```
a:link,a:active,a:visited{text-decoration:none;}
```

for some reason It doesnt work.. If I want to apply this rule, lets say inside div with `id="test"`
I need to use this rule:

```
#test a:link,#test a:active,#test a:visited{text-decoration:none;}
```

and I have no idea why.. Do you have any clue why this is happening?

Comment: You need to remember that `!important` overrides the cascade of CSS; and makes future maintenance that much harder. It's taking a sledgehammer to crack a walnut. The problem you have is that there's a more specific selector, somewhere, targetting those `a` elements. Use Firebug, or Web Inspector, to find out where the styles are coming from and address that selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   a:link,a:active,a:visited{text-decoration:none !important;}
```

Comment: You can use !important to force this style, but you need te be aware that you cannot override this style anymore so I advice to avoid !important as much as possible, see this question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css

Comment: Indeed... fixing simple problems with !important is a bad habbit.

Comment: yes i would not tell anyone to use !important if they can find a better way but some times it can be help full

Answer (score 1):

There's most likely another rule that is overriding the style for your links.  Ideally, use the browser's developer tools to inspect the CSS, that will show you which styles are overriding yours and enable you to debug what's going on.

Alternatively, if you definitely want `text-decoration: none` for **all** links, you can use the `!important` flag to force the styles to apply:

```
a:link, a:active, a:visited { text-decoration:none!important; }
```

Comment: You can use !important to force this style, but you need te be aware that you cannot override this style anymore so I advice to avoid !important as much as possible

Comment: See this question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css

Comment: @Wessel Kranenborg: Fair point, I've updated my answer.  However, I think in this instance `!important` would be more than sufficient for what the OP is wanting to do - as indicated by the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your link rules are defined somewhere else and you need to specify them to make them stronger and overwrite your other definition.

You have to provide more code (both html & css) to locate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I try this in jsfiddle it all works correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/g6Eqx/1/. Do you have another css rule which is stronger than this rule in your css?

Comment: No, I dont have anything stronger than this at my css rules. I added !important like 1ftw1 and Town said and it works. BTW in my other site I got the same rule and it works without the !important

Comment: Can you post the full css/html code to jsfiddle so we can watch at it. If !important is necessary you propably have something else wrong in your css/html

Comment: Given that `!important` helped, you almost certainly _do_ have another rule here that's setting the text-decoration.