# Font-size being ignored in browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

I'm trying to set the font size of a table cell, but its not working. I've tried to set size in the css:

```
.myclass {
  font-size: 10px; 
}
```

It didn't work. I tried to change it to a relative size:

```
.myclass {
  font-size: 0.8em; 
}
```

But it didn't worked either. When i looked at the element using google chrome Developer tools, the font-size tag was there, but was striked out and has a yellow exclamation mark next to it. Does anybody know what it means and how can i set the font size ?

Comment: Post your html as well, there is something wrong for sure.

Comment: I have noticed that this value may be ignored if you make it smaller than a certain size. I was experimenting with this in Chrome devtools today and noticed it wouldn't let me make some fonts smaller than 12px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used a more specific selector to set the font before, the less specific selector won't work. Try to begin with general rules and use the specifics after them.

Comment: might be that, but i solved it using % instead of em. font-size: 85% worked perfectly, and I can still folow the users browsers size configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `!important` following the declaration of the style.  This will override any other styles.

```
.myclass {
  font-size: 0.8em !important; 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css/3427813#3427813

Comment: its just that people tend to misuse power, so please don't arm them :D