# Input buttons different on mac and windows

Tags: html, css, windows, macos, button

Here is my button in code:

```
<!-- CSS Code -->
input {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    width: 87px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

<!--  HTML Code -->
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Student">
```

When I view this button on macbook and my windows laptop, they both look different.

Mac OS:

[image]

Windows 7:

[image]

As you can see the button in the Windows 7 version is much bigger with bigger font. I initially developed this on my Macbook. Do I need to change something in my code? Why is it doing this?

Comment: Did you use a CSS reset?

Comment: Does OS X even let you style the buttons? Also, your button is an `input` element, not a `button`, so it has a font size of `55px`.

Comment: button != input with class button.

Comment: @Blender: The `input. button` selector matches an `input` element with `class="button"`, not a `button` element.

Comment: @Guffa: The original question had `button` as the second selector.

Comment: @Blender I only changed because it may have confusing for some people after hearing these few comment. Whether `input.button` or `button` in the css part, it still is considered the same.

Answer (score 1):

It would look like on the Mac OS the `font-size` is being ignored, probably by design or override by some browser / OS settings.

If you remove font-size do the buttons now look the same in both browsers? If you need to specify the font size you might find some [helpful advice over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025993/font-size-being-ignored-in-browsers).

Comment: Yeah 55 font looks like it's applying only on the Windows screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ttry this css code
.button {
    width: 87px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

Your button css code is a tag, and not a class, so your `class="Button"` is not work, because no exist this css class