# Mobile devices (ipad, nexus 7, samsung y) don't applying !important used in background image applied to body

Tags: css, ipad, responsive-design

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)
        and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .page-id-4194 {
        background: url("http://website.es/wp-content/homepage-bg5.jpg") 
        repeat-x left top 44px #FFFFFA !important;
    }
}
```

I can't get my head around why the background image I applied to the body (code above) works in the desktop computers' browsers but not in mobile devices'.

The code above is meant to override the current background applied to the body.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you missing a `#` before the element ID?

Comment: You probably should try to avoid using `!important` if at all possible also.

Comment: Yes, I was forgetting it, it is a class i was missing the "."

Comment: What can I use instead of !important??? thank youu

Comment: Unfortunately even by adding the "." it still doesn't work :S

Comment: Found it thank you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css

Comment: Any thoughts about how to force the mobile devices into interpreting the background applied to body??

Comment: @user1791939: Two ways, you can simply place the updated css further down the page or you can use [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity) to overwrite something. Also could you provide a sample of your code, a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) perhaps?

Comment: @gaynorvader thanks very much for such an awesome resource, im going to apply it now..

Comment: I managed to make the images show, what was happening was (left top 44px) didn't work on the devices. The key was a better knowledge of specificity in css.