# CSS can't find an image url

Tags: css

The below code is all inline CSS.

DOESN'T WORK

```
#Image {
     background-image: url('Images/home.png');
}
```

DOESN'T WORK

```
#Image {
        background-image: url('http://localhost:63832/Images/home.png');
}
```

But when I copy and paste the url, i can access the image. I can also see this defined and active when I check the css in the browser.

WORKS

```
<img id="Image" src="Images/home.png" />
```

Comment: Maybe you're using a `background` property for `#Image` somewhere else in your code. Are you sure there are no other conflicting styles present. Inspect the `#Image` in your browser and see what all styles are actually applied to it.

Comment: did you tried "background:url("image path") no-repeat: left top;"  like this with background position ?

Comment: use background-image: url('Images/home.png') !important

Comment: `background-image`, while setting the background of the element, doesn't give the element any size. If you're not getting a file_not_found error in the JS console, then the image _is_ being loaded, but is just not visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with width and height properties

```
#Image
{
     background-image: url('Images/home.png');
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the same issue by putting **../../** before the path of the image

```
#Image {
    background-image: url('../../Images/home.png');
}
```

Comment: This may or may not work for the OP, depending on their project setup.

Answer (score 1):

Make the css like

```
 #Image {
     background-image: url('Images/home.png') !important;
 }
```

if it already defined anywhere in your site is replace and add this.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a `background` property for `#Image` somewhere else in your code. Are you sure there are no other conflicting styles present? Inspect the `#Image` in your browser and see what all styles are actually applied to it.

Try using `!important` if you're not sure. But [I would avoid using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427813/1492578):

```
#Image {
     background-image: url('Images/home.png') !important;
}
```