# how to override min-width

Tags: css, overriding

Wanted to use a custom css option, instead of modifying the source code.Is there any possibility to override these css values please ?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .footer-fixed #wrapper [role="main"] {
    padding: 80px 60px 60px;
  }
}
```

not to sure how to apply !important in order to have :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 76.5625em) {
  .footer-fixed #wrapper [role="main"] {
    padding: 80px 8px 20px 30px;
  }
}
```

thank you,

Comment: the syntax is correct you don't have to use !important

Comment: thank you for your reply. just wanted to be sure that I was understood correctly .I don't want to replace the first css code with the second one shown above, directly in the source file, but to use a custom css field in order to override these values. As far as I know , this could be possible only if I use !important rule. thanks

Comment: you css will not be instantly changed until the min-width reach 76.5625em !!

Comment: Thank you, it works without !important too. noob question is it wrong with !important ? :D the loading time will be longer ?

Comment: it's the same with !important and without it in this case , but in general cases have avoid using !important , more more clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css

Comment: all clear now, thank you.I really appreciate it !! :) ps: is there any posibility to choose both answers as solution ?

Comment: choose the answer of @dowomenfart as solution i'm not answering i'm commenting here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would apply !important. Read up more about **[!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm)**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 76.5625em) {
  .footer-fixed #wrapper [role="main"] {
    padding: 80px 8px 20px 30px !important;
  }
}
```

Also, if you are in the same stylesheet as the first selector and declartion block you could add this CSS below it and it should override it without !important.

Comment: It works . Thank you , I thought that I should use the !important rule on the min-width line too somehow. The strange thing is that it works without important too ... as Ze told me above :) at this point I'm pretty confused, not so sure what is the best answer and why ...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using !important  because it could get sloppy. That's why I also had an alternative way without using !important.

Comment: I understand. I'm not in the same stylesheet I try to override using an extra css field .thank you once again, I'll use the code without !important.