# Class selector priority over several unique ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have three unique ID's like so:

```
#green-text {
    color: #57BF90;
}

#grey-text {
    color: #474444;
}

#orange-text {
    color: #FFAC00;
}
```

Which each has a class called `.example-button`. When one of these classes is clicked, I'd like to use jQuery to do

```
$('.example-button').click(function() {
     $(this).addClass('white-text');
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('white-text');
}
```

where

```
.white-text {
     color: white;
}
```

But of course this class doesn't take priority over the ID's so nothing would change. Is there a better way to script this other than

```
.white-up-text#green-text {
    color: white;
}
.white-up-text#grey-text {
    color: white;
}
.white-up-text#orange-text {
    color: white;
}
```

or other than using `!important`? (I'm avoiding `!important` in order to respect good **CSS** practice)

Comment: Use `!important`.. https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/147/

Comment: Or just replace the IDs with classes.

Comment: And regarding `!important`, you can use it sometimes without blowing up, such as for utility classes.

Comment: [No, don't use !important](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css) unless you have literally no other choice (ie. importing external content and you have no control over the styles). Your second approach is the best method - using selector specificity. That said, I normally put `id` selectors first as they have the most weight, ie. `#green-text.white-up-text`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan are you sure if he has 20 classes will duplicate them instead of using `!important`?

Comment: Yes, but then it becomes more about better design of your rules than using `!important`. Classes would be a much better choice for the OP here, instead of his current `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, you can keep nesting your styles in order to increase the specificity and target the element.

You could use `!important` but that should be a last option. Otherwise your code will not be scalable after a certain point and is considered a worst practice.

And put, id's first since they carry more weight (Just a pattern which in no way affects specificity)

```
#green-text.white-text {
    color: white;
}
```

Once you associate a style to an id.

- The only way to override would be is to use !important (Avoid it)
- Use a more specific style (which is always nested inside the id so
  that you are targeting it).
- Use inline style which has a better specificity than the id

In the long run it won't be maintainable. So it is always a better idea to replace it with a `class` instead

```
.green-text.white-up-text {
    color: white;
}
.grey-text.white-up-text {
    color: white;
}
.orange-text.white-up-text {
    color: white;
}
```

Also take a look at **[OOCSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)** which advocates the principle of code reuse, where classes are the king.

Comment: Since when did changing the order of selectors influence specificity?

Comment: @BoltClock That was clearly not my intention as the order does not matter, I must have mistyped. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: But instead of repeating yourself, why not _make use_ of order with same specificity? Have the color class rules (`.green-text{}` etc.) come first, followed by `.white-up-text { color: white; }`

Comment: @CBroe That is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Change your jquery to :

```
$('.example-button').click(function() {
 $(this).css("color","white");
 $(this).siblings().removeAttr('style'); });
```

This works as inline style has greater specificity than id selector.