# Ionic 2 <ion-select> width

Tags: ionic2

The template:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Select long text</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
        <ion-option value="opt1">Very very long text</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

This gets cut off since the default width for  appears to be quite narrow.

How do I change the width?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set ion-select component with 100% width in IONIC 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622159/how-to-set-ion-select-component-with-100-width-in-ionic-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in you .sass file:

```
.alert-wrapper {
   min-width: 40px;//what ever you like
}

.alert-radio-label {
   white-space: normal!important;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to apply it for 1 specific select?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your `sass` file

```
ion-select{
    max-width: 70% !important;// your choice :)
}
```