# Styling ion-select with popover interface

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm creating a an ion-select element with a popover interface.  I would like to style the ion-select-options so that they span the width of the screen but nothing I have tried is working.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
                <ion-button>Cancel</ion-button>
              </ion-buttons>
              <ion-title>Messages</ion-title>
              <ion-buttons slot="primary">
                    <ion-button>Blah</ion-button>
                  </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
  <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-select interface="popover" placeholder="Select an item">
                <ion-select-option value="nes">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the</ion-select-option>          
                <ion-select-option value="n64">Nintendo64</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="ps">Blah Blah Ipsum is simply dummy text of the</ion-select-option>
                <ion-select-option value="genesis">Sega Genesis</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

[image: This is what that looks like:]

I would like the select options to span the width of the screen.  I'm okay with the `...` if any text in the list is longer than the select-option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look into developer console using Inspect. You will see

[image: Popover]

`ion-select` has popover wrapper inside it which actually we need to style according to our requirement.

To achieve what you have mentioned.

You need to add some styles in your `global.scss` for `popover-content`

```
:root {
    .popover-content {
        left: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

You will get the following for both, `ios` and `md`.

[image: ios]

[image: md]

**NOTE:** Do the same using media query and adjust the width so that it won't look awkward in tablets and ipads.

Comment: is there a way to do this without putting it in global?  That will affect all popovers, right?  What if I only want to change this particular one?

Comment: Can you please share full CSS. How you have changed the font? I want to change the font color of the popup text but it is not working if I place it in the popover-content

Answer (score 5):

When you use `interface="popover"` you can set the nested `ion-popover`'s interface options with `[interfaceOptions]="..."`. To display the select options at full-width use `size: 'cover'`:

```
<ion-select interface="popover" [interfaceOptions]="{size: 'cover'}">
</ion-select>
```

See https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#interfaces for more options.

Answer (score 4):

This solution isn't completely ideal since it still requires global css scope, but its at least a bit more descriptive, reusable, and doesn't interfere with base popover functionality like the other solutions...

template.html:

```html
<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="{ cssClass: 'popover-wide' }">
```

global.scss:

```
.popover-wide .alert-wrapper {
  width: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this with css

```css
.popover-content{
  width: 95%
}
```

Comment: this only works when I put it in global.  is there a way to do it without putting it in global?

Comment: Yes, you can aad it to specific page css file or app.component.scss file. I checked it is working

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS Shadow Parts:

```
ion-popover::part(content) {
  --width: 95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest and only 100% working solution for me (ionic 6.7.3 with vuejs and TypeScript) was to set mode to "md". Hope this helps someone.

```
<ion-select
        :placeholder="$t('common.choose')"
        interface="popover"
        mode="md"
        v-model="patientLanguageModel"
        @ion-change="choosePatientLanguage"
        :class="{bigger: currentPatientLanguage}">
        <template
          v-for="(language, i) in languages"
          :key="i">
          <ion-select-option
            :value="language.code"
            v-if="true">
            <p>
              {{ language.name + ' – ' + language[currentAppLanguage] }}
            </p>
          </ion-select-option>
        </template>
      </ion-select>
```