# Ionic Tab active color

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic Tab .I want to show color of my ionic tab blue at starting on view tab .it is working but after click on edit password blue color is displaying on Edit Password  but not removing from view tab.Again clicking on view button then everything is working fine . I created Codepen for that `[http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/WopBLv]`  check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected your [codepen](http://codepen.io/jalef/pen/ZBKEVR) and it works, but the changes where many:

- First of all. The use of !important, as other classes suggest, is not a good idea. When you use important, everyting else is overridden and this will cause problems in finding why some classes do not apply to all the elements etc (take a look at this answer that describes the [problems caused from !important use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427766/should-i-avoid-using-important-in-css) ). !Important must be used with caution and avoided if possible, and in this case, it is possible.
- I corrected the ids at tab items: you should never use the same id for two elements!:

  ```
  <a id="id_view" class="tab-item" ng-click="activeButton = 'a'; showme=false" ng-class="{ 'my_active': activeButton === 'a' }">
       <i class="icon ion-android-people" ></i> View
   </a>
   <a id="id_password" class="tab-item" ng-click="activeButton = 'b'; showme=true" ng-class="{ 'my_active': activeButton === 'b' }">
       <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i> Edit Password
   </a>
  ```
- You don't need two classes. You need the active class. I call it my_active. The `ng-class="{ 'my_active': activeButton === 'a' }` attribute watches the value of the activeButton variable, and if it is equal to 'a', then the element has the my_active class. If not, the element has no class, so it is displayed in it's inactive color. In the same way works the `ng-class="{ 'my_active': activeButton === 'b'` .
- For initializing the active element as the View button, you only need this line in the controller:
  `$scope.activeButton='a';`
  You don't need to access Ids. Avoid accessing elements with ionic and angular. Variables used in view and changed by  controller can give you the same result in a safe and reliable way.

Comment: Thanks Jane. It is perfect solution ,

Answer (score 1):

1) you should create two css classes : active and inactive

```
.myactive{
  background-color: #3166A2 !important;
}
.myinactive{
  background-color: #0a0a0a !important;
}
```

2) you add 'id' property to each link

```
<a id="myId" class="tab-item " ng-click="activeButton = 'a'; showme=false" ng-class="{ 'myactive': activeButton === 'a' }">
    <i class="icon ion-android-people" ></i> View
</a>
```

3) you set active class to view tab in the controller:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#myId')).addClass('myactive');
```

4) you create a function that switch between both classes and you call it using ng-click:

```
var myFunction = function(thisId){
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#thisId')).addClass('myactive');
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#otherId')).addClass('myinactive');
}
```

Hope that helps u :)

Comment: i have updated codepen according to ur suggestion ..no luck http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/WopBLv

Comment: Thanks buddy.Your answer is ok but not perfect becuase you use more js and use black color too, Check first answer ,it is good.

Comment: I just added this color just to show u how it works correctly, if u delete it from css it works as u want ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following code, I have used active function here,

**HTML**

```
<ion-content>
   <div class="tabs tabs-dark tabs-icon-top static">
      <a  class="tab-item " ng-class="{'myactive': isActive1({{1}})}"  ng-click="FunctionCall1(1)">
        <i class="icon ion-android-people" ></i> View
      </a>
      <a  class="tab-item" ng-class="{'myactive': isActive2({{2}})}"  ng-click="FunctionCall2(2)">
        <i class="icon ion-gear-a"></i> Edit Password
      </a>
   </div>
 </ion-content>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myactive{
  background-color: #3166A2 !important;
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $scope.active1=1;
    $scope.FunctionCall1=function(val){
       $scope.active1=val;
       $scope.active2='';
    }

    $scope.FunctionCall2=function(val){
       $scope.active2=val;
       $scope.active1='';
    }

    $scope.isActive1 = function(type) {
        return type === $scope.active1;
    };

    $scope.isActive2 = function(type) {
        return type === $scope.active2;
    };
});
```

***Hope this will helps you !!!!!***

Comment: Thanks but i tried with previous solution and it is working .