# exclude CSS properties in a range of CSS classes

Tags: css

I create custom Pre css properties for specific tasks. After a change on my 'complete' website CSS I can't get these to work again.

I've got for exampe a Pre.PowerShell property:

```
pre.PowerShell {
    background-color: #012456;
    color: #fff !Important;
    font-family: consolas !Important;
    border-top: 8px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

this worked until I added this:

```
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, .comments-title, .search-field, .nav-links, .post-navigation .post-title, .widget-title {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe WP", Arial, sans-serif !important;
    color: #000;
}
```

It overrides the settings I do in Pre.PowerShell. 
I've tried adding these and I think I'm close, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work yet.

```
.PowerShell:not(pre)

pre:not(powershell)

pre:not(Pre.powershell)

pre:not(.PowerShell)
```

I have a hard time understanding the explanation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Comment: Have you tried pre:not(.PowerShell) ?

Comment: Avoid using `!important` in this manner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427813/2930477

Comment: yep, tried pre:not(.PowerShell) as well !

Comment: Your code should work since `pre.PowerShell` is more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than just `pre` Your issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: And this is exactly the reason you shouldn't liberally use `!important`

Comment: i've removed all !important's and it still doesn't work ;-)

Comment: Can you share the markup you're applying this CSS to?