# Stop element.style to overwrite my css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a form in ruby on rails and in that form I'm using a slider (http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/).

The problem is that I have this `element.style` that overwrites my `css` like this:

For stored field:
[image]

When I add a new field dynamically:
[image]

What is this `element.style`?

Why this `element.style` overwrites the `width`?

This `element.style width` has the value `0px` in the first case and `152px` in the second, and I have no ideia why.

Any help?

Comment: You should read about [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). The style attribute was very likely added by the javascript widget. You may only override the style attribute with the unbeloved [`!important` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important` to the rule you don't want overridden. E.g. `.slider.slider-horizontal {width: 210px}`

(using !important is often frowned on, because it can initially enable poorly-structured CSS, and then go on to make your styles extra messy as you start having to use more !important's to override earlier !important's, but there are definitely times when you just have to use it)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369216/how-do-you-read-important-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701149/when-to-use-important-property-in-css, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042497/when-to-use-important-to-save-the-day-when-working-with-css via @cody gray's comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245353/what-does-important-in-css-mean