# css styles not being applied to bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the background color of my navbar, but it's not working.
This is my html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_header.css">
</head>

<body >


<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home page </a> </li>


  <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a{
color: white !important;
}

    .navbar-default {
    background-color: #3232ff !important;
}
```

Before, my css file was like below and it worked:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a{
color: #3232ff !important;
}
```

Now, there is something weird going on, because before i was using the same css file with styles for the `anchor link` color only. Now that I changed it and also added styles for the background color of `navbar` it doesn't work.The color remains the same as before I made the changes.

Comment: I also tried it separately from my project and it works, inside the project it doesn't :/

Comment: In your sample you are importing admin_header.css file which I did not, maybe there is the conflict.

Comment: Eli your question should be remove as it can not be reproduced.

Comment: @eli your code is working I think may be some cache issue try hard reload and than run.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to your navbar, Bootstrap is overwriting your styles.

for example in your css you could do

`.myNavbar.nav.navbar-nav li a {}`

edit: In your html page you are creating, for example just add to `<ul class="nav navbar">` this
`<ul class = "myNavbar nav navbar-nav" >`

edit: here is a jsfiddle
It seems that you don't really understand the important! flag
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37347/

Quoting [slebetman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2042572):

> - **Never** use !important on site-wide css.
> - **Only** use !important on page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css (from ExtJs or YUI for example).
> - **Never** use !important when you're writing a plugin/mashup.
> - **Always** look for a way to use specificity before even considering !important

Comment: How do I add a class to navbar?

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Okay. Let me get a jsfiddle going on first and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
.navbar-nav li a {
            color: white ! important;
        }

        .navbar-default {
            background-color: #3232ff !important;
        }
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: is your admin_header.css file in root folder or other folder

Comment: They're in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

```css
  .navbar-nav li a {
            color: white !important;
        }

        .navbar-default {
            background-color: #3232ff !important;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home page </a> </li>


                <li><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```